# How do I make a custom <form> element be used in place of a <form> in a pre-existing plugin?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, footer

I am customizing a theme and a plugin in Wordpress. The plugin has a button where a user can click to bring up a form where they can ask a question. I want users to use post questions through this button on this plugin, but I don't fancy the visuals on it. So I thought I'd make a form on my landing page that will post into the plugin's form. If this is a terrible idea in the long run, please feel free to let me know because I am still new to web dev.

So the goal is to create a new form whose aesthetics are to my liking but still use the plugin's built in posting capability. How do I make *my* form paste into the *plugin's* form and then submit it? You'll notice that my form has 1 additional field: the add money field. I also need to integrate this into the plugin. If anyone know how to begin modifying the code for this I'm all ears to anything I need to start reading or a general way of how to approach this.

[My form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUaDU.jpg)

[Plugin's form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7OQI.jpg)

Summary:

1. Need to have my form paste to plugn form and submit
2. Need to add a field to the plugin code that my form can post to similar to how the other fields will do do

Comment: we can't help you very much without any code

Comment: @Markasoftware what part of the code should I look for specifically? I wanted to post it, but this is someone else's plugin, so there are a TON of files inside the zip file I have. And since I'm new to web dev I'm not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

You can post from a different form if you get the destination URL or javascript that is handling the original form post. You can use the debugger in Firefox or Chrome to inspect the page contents to see how the form is handled.

Adding the money field will be more complicated because you will need to update the server side handling to accept the additional parameter so that it is not simply ignored or causing errors. How much work this is depends on what the server has to do. It may involve adding a column to the database or creating a new table which you will likely want to do the wordpress way if you want to have something that is maintainable.

Lastly keep in mind, that every time the original plugin is updated, it may bust your add on code unless you create your own plugin from the original.

Comment: Well if I'm customizing the plugin, what benefit would come from downloading updates to the original plugin? Maybe security fixes? Because other than that I am branching it off in another direction because I didn't like the original plugin

Comment: Ok I used the "Inspect Element" tool in Chrome to see what's under the hood. [This is a screenshot of the elements of the form.](http://imgur.com/LF32zEI) What am I supposed to interpret from this?

Comment: You will notice the ap_ajax_form entry in data-action. You need to relate this to the handler in the wordpress javascript that is making the AJAX submission to the server. If you have not yet learned to debug javascript, you will need to do so to understand what the AJAX call is doing and how to add your form entries to it.